# Parsing SO RSS feed using TouchXML, no <entry> tags found

Tags: iphone, xml, rss, xml-parsing, touchxml

I'm trying to parse a Stack Overflow RSS feed of a specific question:
https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/question/2110875

For this I'm using the TouchXML library. There seems to be a problem in the following code:

```
CXMLDocument *parser = [[CXMLDocument alloc] initWithData:sourceData options:0 error:nil];
NSArray *allEntries = [parser nodesForXPath:@"//entry" error:nil];
NSLog(@"Found entries: %d",[allEntries count]); //Returns 0
```

The NSLog statement should return the count of all entries in the feed. In this case it should be '3', problem is that it returns 0.

I found that this piece of code does work:

```
CXMLDocument *preParser = [[CXMLDocument alloc] initWithData:sourceData options:0 error:nil];
NSString *sourceStringUTF8 = [preParser XMLString];
[preParser release];

CXMLDocument *parser = [[CXMLDocument alloc] initWithData:[sourceStringUTF8 dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:0 error:nil];
NSArray *allEntries = [parser nodesForXPath:@"//entry" error:nil];
NSLog(@"Found entries: %d",[allEntries count]); //Returns 3, which is ok
```

But using this seems hacky (it probably is) and introduces a few other sporadic bugs.

As far as I know the Xpath expression is correct. I've checked it using [this](http://www.whitebeam.org/library/guide/TechNotes/xpathtestbed.rhtm) page as well.

Can anyone help me with this problem, or point me in the right direction.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a very similar problem. This has something to do with the xml namespace, which TouchXML doesn't support very well (a known issue).

I believe that in your hack, the namespace wasn't passed into the second parser, that's why it works.

A easier way is just to change

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
```

replaced with simply

```
<html>
```

and xPath now works.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe start by actually using that `error` argument to `nodesForXPath:error` to see if it returns an error? And check if `allEntries` is not `nil` after making that call?

Comment: I've logged an error message and it's null, so there is no error. The problem is that TouchXML simply doesn't return any Nodes for the Xpath statement, while AFAIK it should just find them.